# Interpretation of non-convergence in metric spaces

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

1 .From analysis I know a sequence can either have limit or not. If it has a limit it is said convergent if the limit is finite, divergent if it is $+\infty $ or  $-\infty$. Therefore if someone tells me a sequence is not convergent, I can't help but think that it can either be divergent or its limit does not exist.

Why then in  the context of Cauchy sequences, people seem to interpret "$(x_n)$ does not converge as " it converges but outside the space " instead of the previous interpretation?

I know that "In a metric space $(X,d)$, every convergent sequence is a Cauchy sequence"

**So if a sequence converges outside the space, why people/textbooks say "it doesn't converge"  when in fact it does (outside the space, but it does!) and leave out the other more natural possibilities ( divergence or of inexistent limit)?** If they always wrote  "it doesn't converge **in the space X**", then I wouldn't argue.

Comment: The question is : what do you mean "outside the space". In general, you deal with a space and you have nothing *outside* it (I mean that the space is not defined as a subspace of something else). However, it is true that you can *always* consider a bigger space in which all the Cauchy sequences have a limit, but this space can be very complicated to handle.

Comment: I will add a small example. You can deal with $\mathbb{Q}$ without knowing anything about $\mathbb{R}$ : $\mathbb{Q}$ is a very easy space to construct, and you can make analysis in $\mathbb{Q}$. You can see for example that some sequences of $\mathbb{Q}$ are Cauchy, but don't converge (in $\mathbb{Q}$ !) : e.g., $\sum_{k=1}^n 1/k!$. Of course, you will say : yes but such sequences converges in $\mathbb{R}$. But I will answer : what is your definition of $\mathbb{R}$ ? And this may become little bit circular (since $\mathbb{R}$ can be constructed as limits of Cauchy sequences of $\mathbb{Q}$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't doubt that you have described correctly the concpet of convergent (and divergent) sequence as you have learned it, but you should keep in mind that, by far, the usual definition is: a sequence (of real numbers) converges if it has a limit and it diverges otherwise. So, for instance, the sequence $\bigl((-1)^n\bigr)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ diverges.

Now, if you are working on a metric space $(X,d)$, you can say that a certain sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ doesn't converge on $X$, but that's redundant, since, if you are working on $(X,d)$, then $X$ is your whole universe. So, you can simply say that it doesn't converge (or that it diverges).

It turns out that for *every* metric space $(X,d)$ and for *every* Cauchy sequence of elements of $X$, there is a larger space $\left(\overline X,D\right)$ such that, *on that space*, the sequence converges. Note that asserting that $\left(\overline X,D\right)$ is a larger space means two things:

- $X\subset\overline X$;
- if $x_1,x_2\in X$, then $D(x_1,x_2)=d(x_1,x_2)$.

In particular, the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ may well converge on $\left(\overline X,D\right)$ and diverge on $(X,d)$. The concept of convergence depends upon the space that you are working with.

Comment: So, if I understood well convergence outside the space= divergence? I thought divergence meant only $+-\infty$ limit.  and why is there no mention of indeterminate sequences(like $(-1)^n$)? In analysis you don't usually include those under the indeterminate term but a separate category, do you?

Comment: Concerning your first question, if a sequence converges outside the space the space, then it diverges. But this is *not* an equivalence. A sequence may well diverge in such a way that it doesn't converge on any larger space. Concerning the usual definition of convergence in Analysis, it's the one you will see on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence); with respect to it, the sequence $(\bigl((-1)^n\bigr)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ simply diverges. There is no separate category for it.